# Convert Negative Values to Zero in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

How would I convert a negative value to be zero in SSRS when designing a report?

```
 Example in preview: -2
 Outcome in preview: 0, but actually mean 0
```

I am able to select the textbox where the "-2" is and format its properties to display as "0", but the value behind that "0" is still "-2". I need the "0" to actually be a value of "0".

Comment: You can modify the dataset to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Use expression, e.g.

```
=IIF(Fields!YourField.Value < 0, 0, Fields!YourField.Value)
```

For your specific example:

```
=IIF(Fields!NetDischarges.Value < Fields!ApptKeptWithin7days.Value, 0, Fields!NetDischarges.Value-Fields!ApptKeptWithin7days.Value)
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it still thinks it is a -2. Here is my code... =Fields!NetDischarges.Value-Fields!ApptKeptWithin7days.Value ... This works for every thing in my report but this one instance. NetDischarges is 0 and ApptKeptWithin7Days is 2. Sooooo the answer to that is my issue.

Comment: @RMM And you are saying that this: `=IIFFields!NetDischarges.Value-Fields!ApptKeptWithin7days.Value < 0, 0, Fields!NetDischarges.Value-Fields!ApptKeptWithin7days.Value)` didn't work?

Comment: Correct! I have sum values and percentages not reflecting the change. For example I have to add a value of 5 with that 0 into a sum textbox and that sum still says 3 and not 0.

Comment: @RMM then you don't need it change in one textbox, as I said in a previous comment, you need to change the dataset

Comment: You'd have to be more specific on the "need to change the dataset" part.

Comment: No luck, Yuriy. I got the zero but it still thinks its -2. Thanks anyways, fellas!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query to return the date difference as a calculated field like so:

```
SELECT NetDischarges, ApptKeptWithin7days, 
  CASE WHEN NetDischarges < ApptKeptWithin7days THEN 0 ELSE NetDischarges - ApptKeptWithin7days END AS DaysDifference
FROM MyTable
```

Then use the `DaysDifference` field in your table.